# What is the page structure of a Visualforce Page in Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I'm working in Salesforce1 and having trouble debugging a Visualforce Page. The goal is to watch the scroll of the page, and switch out a button action when the bottom of the page is reached.

On a normal web page you could just track position (when it hits the bottom) with:

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()
```

This does not work for me in SF1 as the scrollTop element is always 0 regardless of scroll position. Any idea what the page structure is within the SF1 app? Is the page in an iframe or is window & document something different than what it would be on a usual salesforce page?

Otherwise, is there a better way to debug Salesforce1 issues?

Answer (score 0):

Once you put visualforce inside SF1 container it is iframed inside the One app container .

If you inspect element via browser then the markup of VF will be iframed

[image]

Any component you add inside S1 one centerStage will be wrapped inside a scroller .

> In mobile/tablet the scroller does not use native CSS scroller but instead cssTransformations .

Any native scroller won't work because of  e.preventDefault() to avoid the viewport bounce in some platforms.

The solution might be simpler if you use lightning component framework and not visualforce as those may provide you events to handle this .

Comment: I thought it was getting placed in an iframe, but using $('iframe').length would return 0. Per your suggestion, i checked the browser and I can inspect and see the iframe as you mentioned, but even so, still get a length of 0 when running $('iframe').length. 

Separately, thank you for your blog on 'Salesforce 1 app Hicups' I found that really helpful! 
http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.ca/2015/12/ios-and-visualforce-in-salesforce-1-app.html

Comment: thats correct ! Inside vf iframe length is 0 .your script is also running inside iframe